# ElasticSearch - How to query top 3 "messages" of distinct "PostId"

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, I have a list of messages with below structure:

PostId - Message type - Message - MessageDate

Ex:

```
post1 , like , "abc ...", 22 Sep 10:00
post1 , like , "def ...", 22 Sep 10:01
post1 , comment , "xyz ...", 22 Sep 10:05

...
post2 , like , "abc ...", 22 Sep 10:00
post3 , like , "def ...", 22 Sep 11:10
....
postn , comment , "xyz ...", 22 Sep 12:05
```

My question, how can we write query to select top 3 new messages of distinct posts. With above sample data, I wish to get

```
Post1 and its messages
Post2 and its messages
Post3 and its messages
```

I am new on ES, please help me.

Comment: this can be done using aggregations. refer this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

Comment: Many thank, but could you please give me a draft query? And can we do it in 1 query or multi?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a combination of [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) with an inner [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). First you build groups of all your messages by their `postid` and then for each group you query the top 3 messages according to a descending `timestamp` value.

```
GET so-posts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_post_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "postid.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_messages": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 3,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more details, please see [my answer on pretty similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389928/returning-logs-with-the-latest-timestamp-out-of-groups-with-unique-ids/46390519#46390519).